# If a function preserves continuity of paths, is it continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a set function between two topological spaces.
If $f$ has the property that for every continuous path $p:[0,1]\to X$, the path $f\circ p$ is continuous, is it true that $f$ is continuous?

If not, what can be required of $X$ or $Y$ for this to hold?

Comment: Hint: Consider a totally disconnected $X$...

Comment: If $X$ has discrete topology then only choice for $p$ are constant functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sufficient condition would be that $X$ is metrizable and, for every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$, there is a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$, such that $\gamma(1/n)=x_n$.